# click function to redirect when approved and rejected to different URL is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, development, jquery, office-365-developer

I have written this code for redirecting to a different site when Approved or Rejected it is working fine but  I have a mandatory field in that task list and with out filling the mandatory field also if we click on the reject and approve button it is redirecting to that URL what can i do to not work when mandatory field is not filled.

```
           $("input[Value$='Rejected']").click(function(){
            window.location="
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check within the function if the mandatory field is filled or not , have an if else condition, if filled, redirect, else return false. Hope this helps!